# ERANAMES and ERAS in angular-locale

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have updated the Nuget packages in an ASP.NET 4.5 Angular project: 
ui-bootstrap-tpls.js is changed from version 0.14.3 - 2015-10-23 (updated 2015-12-01) to 1.0.3 - 2016-01-11; Angular is 1.4.8 since 2015-12-01.

With the new ui-bootstrap-tpls.js i encountered an "undefined join" js error when using the uib-datepicker-popup attribute on an input text ; after some debugging i discovered that the problem is at line 688, the assignation of formatCodeToRegex variable.

In this place are managed the "G" chars for the formattation (not done in the October 2015 version) , where $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS is an valid object, but are undefined $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.ERANAMES and $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.ERAS, so $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.ERANAMES.join fails.

I don't use "G" for date formattation, so after some searching on Google i resolved the problem by commenting the failing part....:

```
.....
{
  key: 'ww',
  regex: '[0-4][0-9]|5[0-3]'
},
{
  key: 'w',
  regex: '[0-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-3]'
}//,
//{
//  key: 'GGGG',
//  regex: $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.ERANAMES.join('|').replace(/\s/g, '\\s')
//},
//{
//  key: 'GGG',
//  regex: $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.ERAS.join('|')
//},
//{
//  key: 'GG',
//  regex: $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.ERAS.join('|')
//},
//{
//  key: 'G',
//  regex: $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.ERAS.join('|')
//}
```

but obviously is not the best solution.
I searched a lot but i don't understand how it works for to have DATETIME_FORMATS.ERANAMES and ERA not undefined.

in the localization files , for example
    http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/i18n/angular-locale_en-us.js
these values are declared, and i'm calling the previous angular locale js in a script tag.

Answer (score 7):

I have just had the same trouble after upgrading to Angular 1.4.9. I have needed upgrading Angular Locale (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/i18n/angular-locale_es-es.js) and the error is solved.

Comment: I tried to install Angular locale from Nuget, but there is still the error.
Angular locale installs a lot of code , but in theory i should have only something as
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/i18n/angular-locale_it-it.js"></script>
Instead of to referring the local files installed by NuGet.
Could you explain how you use Angular locale ?

Comment: Hi @RobertoAlessi. I've import it just after import angularjs library: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/i18n/angular-locale_it-it.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E"></script>